# Loop over different directories and change of file name

Tags: bash, loops

I have the following subject folder structure:

```
./sub-CC0006/func
..
./sub-CC0199/func
```

Within the func folder I have a file called `sub-CC0006_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events.tsv`. When I tried to put the below code in a loop it did not work. (I tried to first loop to each subject directory and then change the .tsv file names based on the different subject number.)

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
         if ($i == "NaN") $i="n/a"
       }
       print $0
 }' sub-CC0006_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events.tsv > sub-CC0006_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events_new.tsv &&
mv sub-CC0006_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events_new.tsv sub-CC0006_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events.tsv
```

Here is an extract from one of the files I am trying to manipulate:

| onset | response_time |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | NaN |
| 12 | 1.4 |

Comment: Can you add an extract of the tsv file for some context?

Comment: I just edited my post and included it thank you for the suggestion. Some more context. I am simply trying to change the NaN in all these files to n/a. However, I am having trouble with the loop.

Comment: Can you post the raw text from the file as opposed to an image?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the content of the files is largely immaterial to the problem the question asks about, which is managing the names of the files so that the output of `awk` is saved somewhere and then the output is moved/copied over the original file.  The `awk` script maps all occurrences of `NaN` in a field to `n/a`, and that's all.  No excitement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic technique for overwriting a file with an edited version of the file uses a generic temporary file name as the intermediary file.

I'm assuming that in the `sub-CC0199` directory, the `func` subdirectory will contain `sub-CC01999_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events.tsv` and that any other files in the directory are to be ignored, and similarly for each other directory.  The script becomes simpler if you simply want to process all the files (or all the `*.tsv` files, or some other pattern match) in each of the `func` subdirectories for each of the subjects.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp "map.XXXXXX")
trap "rm -f $tmpfile; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

suffix="_ses-core2p2_task-loi3_run-01_events.tsv"

for directory in sub-CC0???
do
    file="$directory/func/$directory$suffix"
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        awk '…' "$file" > "$tmpfile" &&
        mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
    fi
done

rm -f "$tmpfile"   # Remove the temporary
trap 0             # Cancel the 'exit' trap; the script exits with status 0
```

If you're worried about preserving links (or ownership, or permissions) on the original file, or that the original file might be a symlink you want to preserve, you can use `cp "$tmpfile" "$file"; rm -f "$tmpfile"` instead of `mv`.  It's slightly slower, though — but unless the files are big, probably not measurably slower.

You could generate the temporary file name within the loop; it might be marginally safer to do so if you're worried about malicious actors.  The file is new (did not exist before) when created by `mktemp`, but after you've moved it, a malicious person could create their own symlink to somewhere sensitive so the script could damage other files unexpectedly. (You could also copy the temporary file over the original without removing the temporary, so the same file is used for each `.tsv` file — the options are legion.) You're probably not working in an environment that hostile, though.

The [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) list is for "EXIT" (0) and signals 1 (SIGHUP), 2 (SIGINT), 3 (SIGQUIT), 13 (SIGPIPE) and 15 (SIGTERM).  I learned to script when only the numbers worked — and they're compact.  If you want to be slightly more modern, you could list the short names of the signals and conditions:

```
trap "rm -f $tmpfile; exit 1" EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM
…
trap EXIT
```

or (to cancel multiple traps, though it's unnecessary when the script is about to exit):

```
trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM
```